# Facets hierarchical taxonomy terms not working

Tags: 8, entities, taxonomy-terms, search

I use the [Facet module](https://www.drupal.org/project/facets) `version 8.x-1.x-dev`. I have a list of taxonomy terms with parents and childs.

The taxonomy term facet is an Entity reference field. I can't get the hierarchical structure working in the frontend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it by re-added the field from `admin/config/search/search-api/index/default_index/fields` and take the `ID` from the index instead of `name`. Then in the Facet settings use `Transform entity ID to label`. Then the hierarchical structure from the taxonomy terms works!

Comment: Thanks @meez this helped me today

Answer (score 0):

I was confronted with the same problem, Meez's comment helped me on my version (Drupal 8.9.9, Search API 1.17.0 and Facets 1.5.0), to have the option `Transform entity ID to label` on the facet, you must not go through the selection of an ID or Name attribute on the taxonomy field in `admin/config/search/search-api/index/MYINDEX/fields`, use it directly in the reference field of taxonomy (`field_myfield_taxonomyreference`). Everything else is fine, thank you.